# AJAX on Form Details

Tags: forms, 9

I have a lot of API calls in a form, so in order to not call everything on load, I only want to load it when the user opens the details element.

But I am having trouble adding #ajax to the element. I can see a spinner and that it calls buildForm(), but it is not triggering the callback method. When I wrap the ajax part inside e.g. an checkbox, it works. Thus, I come to the conclusion that it is something with the details element.

How can I create an ajax callback, when the user opens the details element?

Non-working example with ajax on details:

```
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  [...]
  return [
    '#type' => 'details',
    '#title' => $title,
    '#open' => FALSE,
    '#ajax' => [
      'callback' => [$this, 'openAccordion'],
      'event' => 'click',
    ],
  ];
}

public function openAccordion(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $response = new AjaxResponse();
  return $response;
}
```

Working example where ajax is on a button (just an example):

```
return [
  '#type' => 'details',
  '#title' => $title,
  '#open' => FALSE,
  'widget' => [
    '#type' => 'button',
    '#value' => 'Load',
    '#ajax' => [
      'callback' => [$this, 'openAccordion'],
      'event' => 'click',
    ],
  ],
];
```

Comment: Is this code in your ajax callback?

Comment: Can we see a the full implementation minus irrelevant fields please?

Comment: I added a working example. As seen in the code, the only difference is that ajax is not on `details`.

Comment: How are you determining it is not triggering the callback? Is there a message in the Drupal log? Are there any messages in the JS console?

Comment: Im using xdebug and have set a breakpoint. No console logs and no Drupal logs. Also because of xdebug, I can see it reaches a breakpoint in buildForm after click but it is not hitting the callback method.

Answer (score 2):

I am suspecting you cannot attach #ajax to non-input elements. As the display element does not take an input, it likely doesn't trigger #ajax. You can do the following as a fix.

1. Create a library:

   ```yaml
   details_element_ajax:
     css:
       theme:
         css/details_element_ajax.css
     js:
       js/details_element_ajax.js
   dependencies:
     - core/once
     - core/jquery
   ```
2. Add a details element, and a submit button that triggers the ajax, and attach the library

   ```php
   $form['details'] = [
     '#open' => FALSE,
     '#markup' => '',
     '#attached' => ['library' => 'examplemodule/details_element_ajax',
   ];

   $form['hidden_submit'] = [
     '#type' => 'submit',
     '#value' => $this->t('load_details),
     '#ajax' => [
       'callback' => [$this, 'openAccordion'],
       'event' => 'click',
     ],
   ];
   ```
3. Hide the submit button in the CSS file:

   ```css
   #edit_hidden_submit {
     display:none;
   }
   ```
4. In the JS file, when the details element is opened, click the hidden submit button to trigger the ajax:

   ```
   Drupal.behaviors.displayElementAjax = {
     attach: function(context) {
       const elements = $(context).find('#details_element_ajax').once('myfeature');
       elements.each(function () {
         $(this).click(function() {
           $("#edit_hidden_submit').click();
         });
       });
     }
   };
   ```